# .net entity query

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm have an issue with this entity query that I am hoping to get some help with.

Overall what I am trying to do is query for entries in the `GoalNotes` table as well as include the `Employee` reference for each note. The `GoalNotes` table has a foreign key relating it to the `Employee` table.

I am then trying to query the `GoalNotes` table based on a specific goal id. The `GoalNotes` table has a relation setup to the `Goal` Table as well.

I have three tables that look like the following:

**Employee**
Id,
FirstName,
LastName

**GoalNotes**
Id,
Goal,
Description,
Employee,
CreatedDt

**Goal**
Id,
Description,
CreatedDt

The query I am trying to use looks like this:

```
public List<GoalNotes> LoadGoalNotes(int goalId)
{
    var notes = from note in GoalNotes.Include("Employee")
                where Employee.Any(e => e.Id == note.Employee.Id)
                where note.Goal.Id == goalId
                orderby note.CreatedDt descending
                select note;

    return notes.ToList();
}
```

This method exists in an EntityContext file that contains a partial class for my entity object.
The issue appears to be in how I am trying to include the Employee reference. The query works if I remove the `where Employee.Any(e => e.Id == note.Employee.Id)` line (excluding the employee reference)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't help you fix this query if you don't say what you intend it to do. It's clearly wrong, but as far as I can tell the part you're removing wouldn't do anything useful anyway. What are you trying to accomplish by including it?

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully be clearer. I hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include the employee, you just call `Include` -- nothing else:

```
var notes = from note in GoalNotes.Include("Employee")
            where note.Goal.Id == goalId
            orderby note.CreatedDt descending
            select note;
```

The EF already understands the relationship between `GoalNote` and `Employee` (it's in the EDMX), and you don't need to duplicate this information in every query you write.